# Select control that can't be selected and no highlighting

Tags: html, css

This might be an odd request but I like the brevity of a select control to display some data but I don't want the person to be able to select anything or even have the highlighting happen as they are going over each item. I just need it to be read-only.

When I set the readonly flag on the select it gives me this circle with a line thru it icon (don't want that), it still highlights options as I mouse over them (don't want that), and when I click on an option it closes the select but then clicking it again doesn't show the list anymore (it shows nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the options to `disabled` and use CSS to alter how they appear. `disabled` will prevent hover and selection. The option with `selected` will indicated what will show as the first option.

```
<select id="select" name="pets">
  <option value="1" disabled="disabled" selected>Options</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Dogs</option>
  <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Fish</option>
  <option value="4" disabled="disabled">Snakes</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select option:disabled {
  color: blue;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/47w37u2r/3/

I have this working well in chrome but have not tested all browsers. Looks like hover is still there on firefox.

Comment: Any idea on how to disable when using ng-options to populate the options?

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with Angular but I know in jquery you could you something like the `att()` function to adjust the attributes for an html element. http://api.jquery.com/attr/